# Last variable in arraylist is overriding all variables

Tags: android

**This is my ProductcatalogClass** :

```
public class ProductcatalogClass {
    private ArrayList<ProductClass> productlist;

    public ArrayList addproduct() {        

        // ...
        return productlist;   
    }
}
```

**This is my ProductClass** :

```
public class ProductClass {
    private String productName;
    private String availability;
    private int price;

    // getters and setters
}
...
```

**How should I resolve this?**
**I know some of the methods are not completed but I can't actually finish until I figure out how to fix this arrayList issue**

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single `Product` (I renamed it to a better name) object and adding it repeatdly to the list, so no wonder why you get this. What you could do for a better (and correct) code is having a constructor in this class enabling to construct a new instance and set all the members. For a shorter code, you can use 3 lists (one for each attribute) and iterate over them. This won't scale very well to larger number or attributes however, so I won't show it.

Create a constructor in `Product` :

```
public class Product {
    private String productName;
    private String availability;
    private int price;

    public Product(String productName, String availability, int price) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.availability = availability;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

In the catalog class :

```
public List<Product> addproduct() {
    productList.addAll(Arrays.asList(
        new Product("Dell_1", "Available", 600),
        new Product("Dell_2", "Available", 800),
        new Product("Dell_3", "Available", 590),
        new Product("Dell_4", "Available", 400),
        new Product("Dell_5", "Available", 700),
        new Product("Dell_6", "Available", 530),
        new Product("Dell_7", "Available", 550),
        new Product("Dell_8", "Available", 500),
        new Product("Dell_9", "Available", 700),
        new Product("Dell_10", "Available", 600));
    return productList;
}
```

At this stage you can see this method does not make sense because you are always adding the exact same set of products. I can't answer further if I don't know what you intended to do with this.

Comment: ohh thankuu..can you please show me how can I do that..?

Comment: My intension is to create 5 suppliers and their 10 product with product catalog. This is the list of products of 1 supplier. I want to print all this on my console screen.

Comment: Why is the method always adding the same products ?

Comment: I am also not getting the problem. Now in the catalog class it is showing error that boolean cannot be converted into arraylist.

Comment: And how can I print this from main class?

Comment: I fixed my answer, but I won't give you more information I'm afraid. Your code is not well structured and it does not really show what you want to achieve so...

Comment: Dell_1 Available 600 Dell_2 Available 650 and so on

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you, although I advice you to improve your code more deeply

Comment: Yes. I am just a beginner but yes I will improve my coding skills. Thankss once again

Answer (score 1):

When you add a `Product` to your `productList`, only a reference to that object is actually added (something like pointers in C). So if you add the same object to your list ten times, you will have a list of ten references to one object.

You should create new `Product` every time you want to add it to your list.